# Beautifier to convert semicolons

Tags: javascript

Is there any beautifier that would convert JavaScript code from the traditional style (semicolon at the end of each statement/line) and the modern style (put semicolons only when they are needed in ambiguous places) and back?

By "modern" I refer to this website http://es6-features.org

Actually they seem to have renamed "modern" to "reduced", as few days ago it was called "modern".

This question is not about whether we need semicolons or not, it is just about the tool that could be used to convert between the good and the bad style (whatever you think goes to which category).

Comment: "modern style" ? Please explain!

Comment: How is leaving out semicolons "modern style"? Just about every style guide says that semicolons should not be considered optional.

Comment: semicolons are _optionally_ required, this means in most cases they are totally required

Comment: "Modern" style does not use semicolons only when they are absolutely needed. Semicolons vs. no-semicolons is a bit of a religious war. I see high-level modern developers programming without semicolons. I also see high-level modern developers programming exclusively with semicolons. If you want to track the ASI rules in your head as you program, that's your prerogative but it's not inherently better than always using semicolons. Also, the site you linked to is kind of misleading. They imply that ES6 inherently handles no semicolons better than ES5 but that's not true.

Comment: es6-features.org is some random dude's personal project. Just because he says it's modern or good doesn't mean that it really is.

Comment: As for the actual question, it's off-topic here. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." - [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Juhana we all are just dudes.

Comment: @MikeC I do not think you are right, this rule you are referring to is to protect us from the situation when there could be many answers, like recommending for the best book or a good book or a good tool, here I just ask about any one that could do the job, if there is one.

Comment: @exebook "I just ask about any one that could do the job". There's probably several so there's no "right" answer. That's the problem.

Comment: *All* questions that ask for tool recommendations ask for just one.

Comment: @Juhana I do not ask for a recommendation, recommendation is opinion based, here I just want a link to any such tool if there is. The question could be renamed to "is there a single tool that does that" to make double sure it is not about recommendation, do you think this will do?

Comment: No. It's still asking for a tool, and that's always off-topic, no matter how you word it.

Comment: @exebook Any tool that someone links to you is a [recommendation.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recommendation) If someone found a tool that they hadn't used and had no idea if it was any good (which I guess you could say is not a recommendation) then all you would have done is off-loaded your Google work to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [es6-features](https://github.com/rse/es6-features) repository.
This allows to convert from "traditional" to "reduced", but not the other way.

```
....
code = code.replace(/;/g, "@2@")
...
code = code.replace(/@2@([ \t]?\n|[ \t]+\|?\}|[ \t]+\/\/|$)/g,
   "<span class=semi>;</span>$1")
...
```